# Replace parts of text values with a lookup table?

Tags: r, dplyr, replace, lapply, gsub

How would I replace part of values (question in df1) according to a lookuptable (new.text in names) - which would look like what is in df2. I assume a lapplpy with gsub would do the job but can't figure out the syntax!

```
set.seed(42)
df1 <- data.frame(question = c("Hello - a", "Hello - b", "Goodbye - a", "Goodbye - b"),
                  variable = rnorm(4))

df1
     question   variable
1   Hello - a  1.3709584
2   Hello - b -0.5646982
3 Goodbye - a  0.3631284
4 Goodbye - b  0.6328626


names <- data.frame(text = c("Hello", "Goodbye", "Good Morning"),
                    new.text = c("1", "2", "3"))

names
          text new.text
1        Hello        1
2     Goodbye         2
3 Good Morning        3


set.seed(42)
df2 <- data.frame(question = c("1 - a", "1 - b", "2 - a", "2 - b"),
                  variable = rnorm(4))

df2
  question   variable
1    1 - a  1.3709584
2    1 - b -0.5646982
3    2 - a  0.3631284
4    2 - b  0.6328626
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want the output to look like? Also, your print of df1 at the top doesn't seem to have the right values for the "question" column, based on how you defined it.

Comment: Sorry, copied the wrong df across - this should make sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `stringr::str_replace_all` -

```
df1$question <- stringr::str_replace_all(df1$question, 
                   setNames(names$new.text, names$text))
df1

#  question   variable
#1    1 - a  1.3709584
#2    1 - b -0.5646982
#3    2 - a  0.3631284
#4    2 - b  0.6328626
```